# How forward traffic to nfqueue from particular interface alias?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

Let's say there is physical network interface eno1 and a couple of aliases eno1:0, eno1:1, eno1:2, etc. I want to forward all tcp traffic which goes out of eno1:1 to nfqueue. I use this command. iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eno1:1 -j NFQUEUE And this one doesn't work. I suppose it happens because technically it's eno1 physicall interface. Is it possible to achieve what I declared and if it is then how?

Comment: use the ip of the device migh work

Comment: Yeah, I figured out same solution. It works good! Thanks

Comment: On Linux, a so-called interface alias is an IP address (not an interface) with a label attached to it with the interface name where it's configured plus `:` plus a random identifier appended. This exists solely for the purpose of the 20-plus-years-old-and-obsolete ioctl API used by `ifconfig` that can handle only one IPv4 address per interface: it fakes an interface but only for `ifconfig`. Everything else sees this as an IPv4 address. Including *iptables*. Such alias can be made for example using `ip address add 192.0.2.2/24 dev eno1 label eno1:9` to be compatible with `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution IMHO is,

instead using the Interface name, you should use the ip of the virtual interface instead.

This worked already for iptables and should also work for the most other solutions